# Why does STL's std::sort not work with immutable classes?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl

Std::sort works when class properties are mutable. For example the following code works and the vector is sorted in ascending order as expected.

```
class PersonMutable
{
public:

    PersonMutable(int age, std::string name):
        Age(age),Name(name)
    {
    }



    int Age;
    std::string Name;
};



void TestSort()
{
    std::vector<PersonMutable> people;
    people.push_back(PersonMutable(24,"Kerry"));
    people.push_back(PersonMutable(30,"Brian"));
    people.push_back(PersonMutable(3,"James"));
    people.push_back(PersonMutable(28,"Paul"));

    std::sort(people.begin(),people.end(),
        [](const PersonMutable& a, PersonMutable & b) -> bool
    {
        return a.Age < b.Age;
    });
}
```

But the same class when made immutable isn't compatible with std::sort.

```
class PersonImmutable
{
public:

    PersonImmutable(int age, std::string name):
        Age(age),Name(name)
    {
    }

    PersonImmutable& operator=(const PersonImmutable& a)
    {
        PersonImmutable b(a.Age,a.Name);
        return b;
    }

    const int Age;
    const std::string Name;
};


void TestSort()
{
    std::vector<PersonImmutable> people;
    people.push_back(PersonImmutable(24,"Kerry"));
    people.push_back(PersonImmutable(30,"Brian"));
    people.push_back(PersonImmutable(3,"James"));
    people.push_back(PersonImmutable(28,"Paul"));

    std::sort(people.begin(),people.end(),
        [](const PersonImmutable& a, PersonImmutable & b) -> bool
    {
        return a.Age < b.Age;
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how you'd expct `std::sort` to exchange elements in a sequence without mutating them?

Comment: Also, note that your `operator=` returns a value on the stack by reference, which is going to cause undefined behavior...

Comment: @Agnew Conceptually, sorting the elements in a sequence shouldn't mutate the *items* but rather the *sequence* itself. (For example: if I manually sort playing cards by suit, I'm not modifying the properties of the individual cards; only their positions in the deck.) The confusion indicated in the question stems from the C++ mechanics by which `std::sort` actually operates.

Comment: @Lilshieste: the card analogy holds up better if you're sorting pointers - effectively tracking which cards are where without touching the cards, but when you consider that the vector content are memory locations and it's potentially much more efficient to use assignment to overwrite an element than to destruct/copy-construct (and better yet - swap), the actual behaviour becomes intuitively obvious and desirable.

Comment: Classes with `const` members are more trouble than they are worth, IMO. Encapsulate instead.

Comment: @Lilshieste Yes, but the problem is that unlike a real world object, a C++ object is defined by its memory location - it cannot be moved around.

Comment: @TonyD You're absolutely right, and I understand. I was only trying to point out that this was probably the root of the confusion that led to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++'s `std::sort` requires that the iterators being sorted implement [`ValueSwappable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable).

> Type T is ValueSwappable if
>
> 1. Type T satisfies the Iterator requirements
> 2. For any dereferencable object x of type T (that is, any value other than the end iterator), *x satisfies the [Swappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable) requirements.

And to be swappable, you basically need this to work:

```
using std::swap;
swap(*x, *y);
```

Additionally, `std::sort` requires the following expressions to be valid ([MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible)  and [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable):

> Definitions:
>
> - `t` is a modifiable lvalue of type `T`.
> - `rv` is an rvalue expression of type `T`.
>
> Requirements:
>
> 1. `t = rv;`
> 2. `T u = rv;`
> 3. `T(rv);`

### Your compiler appears to be broken...

The code you have presented **does** meet these requirements. So I'm not sure why your compiler is refusing this code. Your `PersonImmutable` does implement the requirements of `std::swap` because of the `operator=` overload.

### Your immutable object shouldn't meet this requirements though (because it's immutable)...

That being said, your `operator=` overload will cause the compiler to crash, because you're returning a stack variable by reference.

An `operator=` overload should almost always return `*this` by reference. Which requires mutating the object. So it doesn't make much sense in an immutable object.

### Do you really need to sort these objects?

If you have to sort them, there are some options.

1. You can sort a vector of pointers.
2. You can sort a std::list of immutable objects.
3. There's other options too..

### The minimal(ish) testcase for this code...

A valid compiler should accept the following code as valid. It sounds like yours does not.

```
#include <string>

class PersonImmutable {
    public:
        PersonImmutable(int age): Age(age) {}

        PersonImmutable operator=(const PersonImmutable& a) {
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        const int Age;
};

int main() {
    PersonImmutable a(1, "a");
    PersonImmutable b(2, "b");

    using std::swap;
    swap(a,b);
}
```

Comment: You are missing the MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable requirement for the value type.

Comment: @DieterLücking: That's actually only required if you use the std::swap overload. If you use a custom swap, that's not actually required.

Comment: The reason it doesn't compile (at least on gcc for me) appears to be because the second parameter of lambda is a reference to non-const while some internal helper function makes the argument a const ref. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), the signature of comparator doesn't neccesarily have to take const-refs, so maybe it's indeed a bug in the standard library. But the code in OP is broken anyway, so... don't know.

Comment: @sharth Have a second look at 25.4.1.1 sort

Comment: @DieterLücking: Well that's pretty clear that I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Also: Having an assignment operator makes the object mutable (However, the OP's code has that broken operator)

Comment: @DieterLücking : How does having an '=' assignment operator make the object mutable. You are making an exact copy of the existing object not changing it's properties.

Comment: @sharth: Thanks for pointing out the '=' bug . I have since fixed that but the sorting is still broken. Using your swap code does suggest my compiler may be broken. Do I need to re-install this ?

Comment: @user2822838 PersonImmutable a(1); PersonImmutable b(2); a = b; // a has mutated